# Can I develop visual studio extension for viewing Web User Control in temp web page?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, add-in, visual-studio-addins, web-user-controls

I work now in a huge project that we build all interface as Web User Controls .. every time I want to view & test one i should add it in web page and then view ..
**I think in a way to develop a visual studio extension that show "View in Temp Web Page" when I make right click on a user control to allow me view user control in a generated temp web page without needing to add it in a test page each time i want to test

but i don't know is there any way to achieve that ... Is  it possible to develop such a thing  ?**